# Get-Content and show control characters such as `r - visualize control characters in strings

Tags: powershell, diagnostics, control-characters

What flag can we pass to `Get-Content` to display [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) such as `\r\n` or `\n`?

What I am trying to do, is to determine whether the line endings of a file are in the Unix or Dos style. I have tried simply running `Get-Content`, which doesn't show any line ending. I have also tried using Vim with `set list`, which just shows the `$` no matter what the line ending is.

I would like to do this with PowerShell, because that would be mighty useful.

Comment: `Get-Content $File | Out-String` usually works when you need the whole file as a string, but might change things.  I suppose you could then use multiple `-replace` operators like `-replace "\`r", "\r"` to replace every special character you need.  Alternately, iterate through every character, cast it to an `[Int]` and see if it's a control character.  Might have problems with non-ASCII characters, so make sure you've got the right encoding.  It might be easier in the long run to use [`System.IO.StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @BaconBits this looked more like an awesome answer than a comment ;)

Comment: @MickyBalladelli Maybe, but I haven't actually tested doing what the question has asked, so I don't know if it actually will work.  For example, I'm not sure how `Get-Content` might change control characters when it pipes to `Out-String` if it gets the file as a string array and then pipes the array to another cmdlet. The question is also lacking details and contains nothing about what the was tried or errors that occurred. It's not even clear what he means by "display." What if he's looking for badly-formed line endings?  I'm a bit leery of answering a somewhat poor question.

Comment: @BaconBits I added more details about what I have tried and what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use Get-Content's -Encoding parameter e.g.:

```
Get-Content foo.txt -Encoding byte | % {"0x{0:X2}" -f $_}
```

If you have the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com), you can use the Format-Hex command:

```
Format-Hex foo.txt

Address:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F ASCII
-------- ----------------------------------------------- ----------------
00000000 61 73 66 09 61 73 64 66 61 73 64 66 09 61 73 64 asf.asdfasdf.asd
00000010 66 61 73 0D 0A 61 73 64 66 0D 0A 61 73 09 61 73 fas..asdf..as.as
```

If you really want to see "\r\n" in the output than do what BaconBits suggests but you have to use the -Raw parameter e.g.:

```
(Get-Content foo.txt -Raw) -replace '\r','\r' -replace '\n','\n' -replace '\t','\t'
```

Outputs:

```
asf\tasdfasdf\tasdfas\r\nasdf\r\nas\tasd\r\nasdfasd\tasf\tasdf\t\r\nasdf
```

Comment: `(Get-Content foo.txt -Raw) -replace '\r','\r' -replace '\n','\n' -replace '\t','\t'` does it. It's very interesting that we can usefully replace `\r` with `\r`.

Comment: ++; just to provide historical context and an update: `Get-Content -Raw` requires PSv3+; PSv5+ ships with its own [`Format-Hex` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/6/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex).

Answer (score 8):

Below is **custom function `Debug-String`, which visualizes control characters in strings**:

- using PowerShell's own `` ` ``-prefixed escape-sequence notation (e.g., `` `r `` for CR), where such a native PowerShell escape is available (see [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters)),
- falling back to [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) (e.g., the ASCII-range control character with code point `0x4` - END OF TRANSMISSION - is represented as `^D`).

  - Alternatively, you can use the `-CaretNotation` switch to represent *all* ASCII-range control characters in caret notation, which gives you output similar to `cat -A` on Linux and `cat -et` on macOS/BSD.
- all other control characters, namely those *outside the ASCII range* (the ASCII range spanning code points `0x0` - `0x7F`) are represented in the form `` `u{<hex>} ``, where `<hex>` is the hex. representation of the code point with up to 6 digits; e.g., `` `u{85} `` is Unicode char. [`U+0085`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/85/), the NEXT LINE control char.; this notation is now also supported in expandable strings (`"..."`), but only in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).

Applied to your use case, you'd use (requires **PSv3+**, due to use of `Get-Content -Raw` to ensure the file is read *as a whole*; without it, information about the line endings would be lost):

```
Get-Content -Raw $file | Debug-String
```

Two simple examples:

---

Using PowerShell's escape-sequence notations. Note that this only *looks* like a no-op: the `-prefixed sequences inside "..." strings create actual control characters.

```
PS> "a`ab`t c`0d`r`n" | Debug-String
```

```
a`ab`t c`0d`r`n
```

Using `-CaretNotation`, with output similar to `cat -A` on Linux:

```
PS> "a`ab`t c`0d`r`n" | Debug-String -CaretNotation
```

```
a^Gb^I c^@d^M$
```

---

##### `Debug-String` source code:

Note: The function below is **also available as [an MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1) with *additional functionality***, notably **showing spaces as `·`** and the **option to show non-ASCII characters as escape sequences** (`-UnicodeEscapes`), and the **option to print a string as a PowerShell string literal** (`-AsSourceCode`). Only the Gist will be maintained going forward.

Assuming you have looked at the linked code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), **you can install it directly as follows**:

```
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1/raw/Debug-String.ps1 | iex
```

```
Function Debug-String {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
    [string] $String
    ,
    [switch] $CaretNotation
  )

  begin {
    # \p{C} matches any Unicode control character, both inside and outside
    # the ASCII range; note that tabs (`t) are control character too, but not spaces.
    $re = [regex] '\p{C}'
  }

  process {

    $re.Replace($String, {
      param($match)
      $handled = $False
      if (-not $CaretNotation) {
        # Translate control chars. that have native PS escape sequences into them.
        $handled = $True
        switch ([Int16] [char] $match.Value) {
          0  { '`0'; break }
          7  { '`a'; break }
          8  { '`b'; break }
          12 { '`f'; break }
          10 { '`n'; break }
          13 { '`r'; break }
          9  { '`t'; break }
          11 { '`v'; break }
          default { $handled = $false }
        } # switch
      }
      if (-not $handled) {
          switch ([Int16] [char] $match.Value) {
            10 { '$'; break } # cat -A / cat -e visualizes LFs as '$'
            # If it's a control character in the ASCII range, 
            # use caret notation too (C0 range).
            # See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation
            { $_ -ge 0 -and $_ -le 31 -or $_ -eq 127 } {
              # Caret notation is based on the letter obtained by adding the
              # control-character code point to the code point of '@' (64).
              '^' + [char] (64 + $_)
              break
            }
            # NON-ASCII control characters; use the - PS Core-only - Unicode
            # escape-sequence notation:
            default { '`u{{{0}}}' -f ([int16] [char] $_).ToString('x') }
          }
      } # if (-not $handled)
    })  # .Replace
  } # process

}
```

For brevity I haven't included the comment-based help above; here it is:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Outputs a string in diagnostic form.

.DESCRIPTION
Prints a string with normally hidden control characters visualized.

Common control characters are visualized using PowerShell's own escaping 
notation by default, such as
"`t" for a tab, "`n" for a LF, and "`r" for a CR.

Any other control characters in the ASCII range (C0 control characters)
are represented in caret notation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation).

If you want all ASCII range control characters visualized using caret notation,
except LF visualized as "$", similiar to `cat -A` on Linux, for instance, 
use -CaretNotation.

Non-ASCII control characters are visualized by their Unicode code point
in the form `u{<hex>}, where <hex> is the hex. representation of the
code point with up to 6 digits; e.g., `u{85} is U+0085, the NEXT LINE
control char.

.PARAMETER CaretNotation
Causes LF to be visualized as "$" and all other ASCII-range control characters
in caret notation, similar to `cat -A` on Linux.

.EXAMPLE
PS> "a`ab`t c`0d`r`n" | Debug-String
a`ab`t c`0d`r`n

.EXAMPLE
PS> "a`ab`t c`0d`r`n" | Debug-String -CaretNotation
a^Gb^I c^@d^M$
#>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using a regular expression replacement:

```
function Printable([string] $s) {
    $Matcher = 
    {  
      param($m) 

      $x = $m.Groups[0].Value
      $c = [int]($x.ToCharArray())[0]
      switch ($c)
      {
          9 { '\t' }
          13 { '\r' }
          10 { '\n' }
          92 { '\\' }
          Default { "\$c" }
      }
    }
    return ([regex]'[^ -~\\]').Replace($s, $Matcher)
}

PS C:\> $a = [char[]](65,66,67, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)

PS C:\> $b = $a -join ""

PS C:\> Printable $b
ABC\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\t\n\11\12\r
```