# How to concatenate string variables with backslashes to create a UNC path in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

This seems like it should be a trivial thing.

I am using Powershell v5.1 and I am trying to build a UNC path from 2 strings that represent a server and a share. Given that $Server hold "Distribution" and $Share holds "Publish"...

```
 $Path = "\\" + $Server + "\" + $Share
```

The output I am getting for $Path is..

```
\\Distribution Publish\
```

I tried changing it to...

```
$Path = "//" + $Server + "/" + $Share
```

...as a test thinking the special character "\" was causing a problem, but then I still get the odd sequence where there is a space between server and share and the 2nd slash is at the end.

```
//Distribution Publish/
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure `$server` and `$share` contain what you think, and they're not in fact eg `$server == "Distribution Publish"` and `$share == ""`? What you have [should be fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi6lk.png).

Comment: Can't reproduce in PowerShell 5 and it would indeed be very odd. Check `$Server.Length` and `$Share.Length` to see if they contain any interesting invisible characters that might influence the result (like RTL markers).

Comment: As substitution functions within double quotes, `$Path = "\\$Server\$Share"` will do what you want.

Comment: @JamesC.: While that is true and is generally a more concise alternative, it is equivalent to what the OP tried and therefore doesn't explain the symptom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your symptoms cannot be explained if your `$Server` and `$Share` variables truly contain *just* `Distribution` and `Publish`, respectively, with *no hidden control characters*.

Here's a contrived example of variable values that do produce your symptom:

```
> $Server = 'Distribution', 'Publish'; $Share = "`r"; "\\" + $Server + "\" + $Share
\\Distribution Publish\
```

<sup>As James C. points out, a more concise alternative for building the string is: `"\\$Server\$Share"`.

As TheIncorrigible1 points out, it is better to build paths using `Join-Path`.</sup>

- `'Distribution', 'Publish'` is an *array* of strings, whose elements PowerShell *concatenates with a space* (by default) when converting it to a string, which in this case results in `Distribution Publish`.
- `` "`r" `` creates control character CR (`0xD`), which, *when printing to the console*, resets the cursor position to the *first column* and prints the remainder of the string there (which in this case is empty).
  Note, however, that the CR is still a part of the string, albeit an invisible one.
  If you want an easy way to inspect a given string for hidden control characters, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356836/45375) of mine.

---

**Update**:

The OP reports that it turned out to be how the `$Server` and `$Share` variables were bound via *parameters*, through **mistaken use of (C#) method-invocation syntax**:

```
# Correct invocation: $Server binds to 1st parameter, $Share to 2nd.
./script $Server $Share

# INCORRECT: Binds *both* values to the *first* parameter, as an *array*
#            and assigns nothing to the second.
#            In PowerShell, "," constructs an array.
./script($Server, $Share)
```

The tricky thing is that `./script($Server, $Share)` happens to be valid PowerShell syntax too, only with different semantics: `$Server, $Share` constructs a 2-element *array* whose elements are the values of `$Server` and `$Share`, respectively.

To avoid this pitfall, PowerShell offers strict-mode setting `Set-StrictMode -Version 2`, which reports an error when method-style invocation is attempted. Note, however, that this setting invariably enables other checks as well, notably causing an error when referencing non-existent properties - see [`Get-Help Set-StrictMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode).

Comment: @EiEiGuy: Glad to hear it. I see; yes, passing arguments C#-style is a common pitfall - please see my update.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid string addition like you're doing when working with paths; there are cmdlets that handle that.

```
$Server = '\\This.server.name'
$File = 'something.exe'
$UNC = Join-Path $Server $File
```

---

Additionally, do string validation if you're running into weird errors.

```
If (!$Server) { "Stuff"; Return } # Checks empty string
If (!$File)   { "Stuff"; Return }
If (!(Test-Path $UNC)) { "Stuff"; Return } # error checking for the file
```

Comment: What I am doing is accepting a server name and a share name as arguments to my file copying script and trying to validate the destination UNC up front. I am stripping any user provided "\" or "/" characters and then building the correct \\server\share path before I call Test-Path. I will give you a +1 for Join-Path though

Comment: Yes, `Join-Path` is good advice. @TheIncorrigible1: your UNC path is missing a _share_ component, however. Also, I suggest not using `Return` for error handling.

Comment: Yes, ideally you'd be using `[CmdletBinding()]` and `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()`, but this was a quick example.  The share can be specified in the `$Server` variable or more aptly renamed to `$Share`