# Cannot convert value to type "System.Version"

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, system.version

I cannot convert a properly formatted string stored in a variable into a version type. The issue must be with the variable as it works fine if I provide the value manually but I don't know what could be wrong with it. I am new to PowerShell so I'm not sure where to look.

Here's my variable:

```
Write-Host "$env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER"
1.0.0.20​
```

Is it really a string? Yes:

```
($env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER).GetType().fullname
System.String
```

Let's convert it into a version:

```
[version]($env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)
Cannot convert value "1.0.0.20​" to type "System.Version". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

Works just fine when tried manually:

```
[version]("1.0.0.20")
```

Any idea what's wrong with my variable? I can't change it as it's provided to me as is.

Thanks!

Comment: take a very very very careful look at your string ... i suspect that it has something that is not a digit or a dot in it. possibly a trailing space? feed it to `Format-Hex` so you can see what it actually contains.

Comment: Good point, @Lee_Dailey, but note that surrounding whitespace isn't the issue (it is ignored). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356836/45375) contains a function that visualizes non-printable characters in a friendlier fashion.

Comment: Great advice! Thanks! Found this non-printable gibberish at the end: 1.0.0.20â€‹

Comment: Good find.  I was just about to post you inspect it with: `0..($env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER.Length-1) | % {[byte][char]($env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER[$_])} `

Comment: @Bluonic - neato! glad to know that you found the glitch ... [*grin*]

Comment: @mklement0 - ah! i didn't know that the `[version]` stuff would toss out trailing spaces. good to know. that function is handy ... but seems like overkill  for this kind of glitch. i should have suggested what `Kory Gill` suggested as a somewhat more direct method - the `.Length` info is a neat & quick sanity check.

Comment: Or replace all characters that are not a dot or a digit like `[version]($env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER -replace '[^\d.]')`

Comment: I ended up cleaning up the variable with: `[version]($env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER -replace "[^ -~]")` which removes all non printable characters. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Glad to hear it, Bluonic. I encourage you to post your solution as an answer, to benefit future readers; however, I recommend using @Theo's approach for robustness.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but within my Azure DevOps pipeline (PowerShell task).

I solved this by placing extra brackets around [Version]$someVariable, so it would be like: ([Version]$someVariable)

Comment: I also had this error in an Azure DevOps pipeline, but the fix did not work for me.