# Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '‪c' does not exist

Tags: powershell

I ran into this problem today. I have reduced my script to nothing but `gci '‪c:\'` and it is throwing this error.

`Get-PSPath` clearly lists a C drive and I have not experienced any other significant PowerShell issues until today.

Answer (score 3):

The root of my issue appears to be a Windows 10 bug.

I had copied a path from the `Security` tab of the `Properties` dialog for a folder. This field now contains a non-printable character at the start.

Interestingly, when I copy/pasted it into my browser for this question, it got stripped out. The only way to diagnose it was to convert it to hex in Notepad++.

Comment: Good to know. As for how to visualize hidden characters from within PowerShell, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27233342/45375).