# Single space between letters of Win32 executable output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

my $PSVersion output is as follows:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.0.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.0.1
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19041
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

If I run

```
wsl -l
```

my output appears in the console as:

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-20.04 (Default)
ubuntu-20.04-systemd
```

If I run

```
wsl -l | Out-File foo.txt
```

it appears in the file as:

```
W i n d o w s   S u b s y s t e m   f o r   L i n u x   D i s t r i b u t i o n s : 
 
 
 U b u n t u - 2 0 . 0 4   ( D e f a u l t ) 
 
 
 u b u n t u - 2 0 . 0 4 - s y s t e m d
```

I've tried specifying different output encodings to Out-File to no avail. I'd like to understand what's going on and how to get around it.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try the [Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1#parameters) parameter on `Out-File` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`wsl -l` unexpectedly uses the UTF-16LE ("Unicode") character encoding for its output**, resulting in extra `NUL` bytes (`0x0`) getting inserted between ASCII-range characters (which can *appear* like spaces) when PowerShell interprets the output (which it invariably does if you *capture or redirect* the output; *display in the console* is *not* affected), based on the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, which defaults to the system's active OEM code page.

The solution is to **(temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to match `wsl`'s output encoding**:

```
$orig = [Console]::OutputEncoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode # UTF-16LE

wsl -l > foo.txt # > is effectively like Out-File

[Console]::OutputEncoding = $orig
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356836/45375) for custom function `Debug-String`, which facilitates diagnosing such encoding problems.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you. If you have the time and inclination, would you explain how you discovered that the UTF-16LE encoding was being used in the output?

Comment: My pleasure, @anonmous; please see the link I've added to the bottom of the answer.