# why is the switch statement not working correctly

Tags: powershell

```
### created arrays
$cell = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$filepath = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$index = $cell.IndexOf($_)
### this code pulls values from excel spread sheet as well as that files name and path 
Get-ChildItem C:\UserS\chaos\OneDrive\Documents\working\srs\dynamic*  | ForEach-Object {
    $xl = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
    $xl.Visible = $false
    $woorkbookactive = $xl.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)
    $woorksheetactive = $woorkbookactive.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    $RANGE = $woorksheetactive.Range("A4")
    $cell.Add($RANGE.Value())
    $filepath.Add($_.FullName)
    $xl.Quit()
}
### the Above code produces these values
Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Left                                   
Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Active                                     
Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Active Permission Type: RESOURCE SCHEME    
###

$cell
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
switch -exact ($cell)
{
 'Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Active  Permission Type: RESOURCE SCHEME'{Write-Host "Found RS";Write-Host $index};#Rename-Item -Path $filepath[$index] -NewName "DynamicRS.xlsx";continue}
 'Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Left'{Write-Host "Found Left";Write-Host $index};#Rename-Item -Path $filepath[$index] -NewName "DynamicLeft.xlsx";continue}
 'Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Active' {Write-Host "Found Active";Write-Host $index};#Rename-Item -Path $filepath[$index] -NewName "DynamicActive.xlsx";continue} 
default{write-host "no match found"}
}
```

I have tried with both regex and if statements however the values keep saying no match even though I can clearly see the matches

the output i received was this

```
no match found
no match found
no match found
```

I was expecting this

```
Found RS
found Left
Found Active
```

and sometimes it does detect them however the output it classes was wrong for example RS become Left
and active Become Left.

Comment: Are those spaces at the end of the values actually part of them? Try `switch -exact ($cell.Trim()) ...`

Comment: Try: `switch -exact ("$cell")`

Comment: @iRon, that would convert the entire array list to a single string, which I don't think is the intent.

Comment: Aside from what @jkiiski points out, there's no obvious problem with your code. If `.Trim()` doesn't fix your problem, please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You also need to declare the `$xl` object only once, above the loop. Then after the loop you do `$xl.Quit()` and release the COM objects you have used: `$woorksheetactive`, `$woorkbookactive` and `$xl`. Inside the loop is is advisable to close the workbook once you have taken the value you need with `$woorkbookactive.Close()`. The way your code now works keeps claiming memory and never frees that so eventually you will run into resource problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want Break vs Continue at the end of your switch cases.

```
PS> $CellValues = @(
                'Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Active Permission Type: RESOURCE SCHEME'
                'Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Left',
                'Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Active'                                    
                )

ForEach ($cell in $CellValues) {

switch -exact ($cell)
{
 'Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Active Permission Type: RESOURCE SCHEME' {
                                                Write-Host "Found RS"     
                                                Break}
 'Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Left'   {Write-Host "Found Left"
                                                Break}
 'Selected Criteria: Enrolment Status: Active' {Write-Host "Found Active"
                                                Break} 
  default{write-host "no match found"}
}

} #End ForEach

Found RS
Found Left
Found Active

PS>
```

P.S. There is an extra space in the first select between Active and Permission.

Comment: While using `break` is good practice and avoids unnecessary processing, it cannot be expected to make a difference here, given that all the branch conditions use distinct strings and exact matching is used.

Comment: @RetiredGeek your code works when passing the strings directly in the array however when i try to pull them form the excel spreadsheets before adding them to the array list the same problem occurs and I cant seem to see any reason for this happening

Comment: For debugging try adding a $Cell.Length before the sleep command and lengthen the sleep time so you can manually count the characters & spaces on the display and match to the value provided by the Length property.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone it was just the annoying hidden control characters where present in the string i was trying to match against

Answer (score 0):

To bring closure to this question:

**There was nothing wrong with your [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement per se** (although its efficiency could be improved - see next section).

As you state, **the real problem was** (emphasis added):

> it was just the **annoying hidden control characters** were present in the string i was trying to match against

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356836/45375) shows how you can visualize hidden control characters in strings.

---

As an aside:

It is **good practice** to **use `continue` or `break` in a given `switch` statement's branch script block** (other than the `default` block)  in order **to prevent unnecessary evaluation of later branches / additional inputs .**

With a *single* input to a `switch` statement, **`continue`** and **`break`** equally stop processing, but with an *array* (collection) as input, their behavior differs:

- `continue` stops processing of the current array element only and *continues with the next one* (if any)
- whereas `break` *exits* the `switch` statement instantly.

The following examples illustrate the difference:

```bash
# SINGLE input
# -> 'found!'
# Without `break`, 'never get here' would be output too.
# `continue` in lieu of `break` works too.
switch -Regex ('one') {
  '.ne' { 'found!'; break }
  'on.' { 'never get here' }
}

# ARRAY (COLLECTION) input
# -> 1, 2
# `continue` moves to the next array element, `break` exits the whole statement.
switch -Regex ('one', 'two', 'three') {
  '.ne' { 1; continue } # move to next element
  'two' { 2; break } # stop processing of the whole statement
  'on.' { 'never get here' }
  'three' { 'never get here' }
}
```

Note re the `default` branch:

- There is *no* point in using `continue` in the `default` branch's action script block, because it is *implied*.
- By contrast, `break` may be used in order to *stop processing further inputs* in case of array-valued input.